# What does "Rotating airfoils of engines" mean in the US Code of Federal Aviation Regulations?

Tags: faa-regulations, propeller, faa

In [part 1.1 of the US 14 CFR](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/part-1/section-1.1#p-1.1(Propeller)), definitions and abbreviations, a propeller is defined as:

> ...a device for propelling an aircraft that has blades on an
> engine-driven shaft and that, when rotated, produces by its action on
> the air, a thrust approximately perpendicular to its plane of
> rotation. It includes control components normally supplied by its
> manufacturer, *but does not include main and auxiliary rotors* or
> **rotating airfoils of engines**.

What is a rotating airfoil of an engine if not a propeller? The italicized section excludes rotors of rotorcraft so what does "rotating airfoils of engines" exclude from the definition of a propeller?

Answer (score 7):

Compressor and turbine blades.  Whether from a turbocharger, a supercharger, turbo-compound, or a turbine (jet) engine.